# Sitecore Developer Center Line Numbers

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to show line numbers in the Developer Center when editing xslt files?  If so, how?  The errors that are given reference line numbers and it's a real pain to count lines manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible (without rewriting the SheerUI app).

Try running the code more often - that way, you'll know roughly where in the code the error lies.

Unless you're only making minor adjustments, it's a lot easier to edit the xslt files in a seperate editor.